# Windows 7 logs out completely when RDP session is disconnected

Tags: windows-7, rdp

I have a Windows 7 PC that I RDP into when I work remotely. I'm having an issue where this machine logs me out completely whenever I end the RDP session. I am not initiating a logoff. This happens when I click the "X" in the remote desktop bar, or if I lose the network connection for some reason. The next time I RDP back into it, or log in from the console, I get a completely new session. This is particularly annoying when I have a shaky internet connection and I have to run something that takes a few hours to complete.

I have checked the Event Viewer to see if there's anything that looks unusual, but I might not know what I'm looking for, even if I see it. The only event that I see that is close to the time of logoff is an actual Logoff event in the Security sub-section of the Windows Logs section:

```
An account was logged off.

Subject:
    Security ID:        domain\username
    Account Name:       username
    Account Domain:     domain
    Logon ID:       0x1377093d6

Logon Type:         3

This event is generated when a logon session is destroyed. It may be positively correlated with a logon event using the Logon ID value. Logon IDs are only unique between reboots on the same computer.
```

I checked the Group Policy (under `Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Remote Desktop Services\Remote Desktop Session Host\Session Time Limits`) to see if there was a timeout set for inactive sessions, and I experimented with changing the values of these settings, but nothing seems to affect it.

Comment: This seems very unusual, but interesting. Does the logoff happen *immediately* after you hit the "X" in the remote desktop bar? If not, how long (seconds, minutes) does it take for the session to timeout and logoff?

Comment: It doesn't seem to be any particular amount of time. Sometimes I am able to immediately resume my sessions, other times, I can connect about 10 minutes later. Other times, the logoff is immediate. This is part of what makes it so frustrating. It's not consistent. I originally suspected that there might be something running in the background that was killing the session at a certain interval, but that doesn't seem to be the case. Yesterday, when I was working, I got disconnected 4 times, and each time, when I immediately reconnected, I got a new logon.

Comment: OK. That is good information. The inconsistency will make this very difficult for you, but it can be narrowed down. Is it possible to be in the same room with the computer that you will RDP into? For troubleshooting purposes, it can be helpful to have both local and remote access at the same time; you can watch the screen and see how the other machine responds your actions.

Comment: Yes. I RDP in from my notebook, and I'm at my console 3 days per week.

Comment: It may be worthwhile to note the various timeout lengths, to see if there is a pattern. While you are logged in via RDP, the local screen should be locked, and should have a little message that says `"Logged in remotely from..."` When you are logged off, that little message should disappear (does it disappear when you are auto-disconnected?)

Comment: And you could also write a batch script or small program that only runs while you are logged on -- and would be stopped when you are kicked off. This could also help track the timeouts to see if there is a pattern.

Comment: That last is w good idea to try to track the timeouts. I will do some experiments tomorrow to find out about the login screen messages, and how they change. It would definitely be worth a few hours to try to get this resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Are you connecting to the "Admin" session?  This implies a "console" connection which will be broken when disconnected.

Comment: Thanks for responding, but the answer is "no". I am connecting with my regular user.